# Determining whether a sequence of coin flips is random

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

Say we have observed a finite sequence of coin flips. Is there a metric for how likely this sequence is generated by a truly random coin flip.

For example, if we flip a coin 1000 times presumably seeing 500 heads and then 500 tails is less likely than a random assortment of Heads and Tails.

Also, presumably we would not see every even flip be a tails and every odd flip to be a heads.

Comment: Unfocused question. You conflate two possible goals: (1) Judging whether the coin is _fair;_ that is P(H) = P(T) = 1/2; (2) judging whether coin flips are performed _independently._ (1) . Either way, you will not _determine_ anything. You can make statements about whether the behavior of the coin is consistent with fairness or independence. // For (1), a z-test can help judge whether the coin seems clearly biased. For (2) runs tests and criteria based on autocorrelation may be helpful.

Comment: Comment about 500:500 split is uninformed, but you are right that it might raise suspicions. Comment about alternating H's and T's is more useful:  that would result in way too many 'runs' and be good evidence against randomness.  // Empirical coin-tossing experiments have shown that anything that looks vaguely like a coin is likely to be very nearly fair. However, great care must be taken to ensure that successive tosses are truly independent. (Diaconis & Holmes have a paper on both fairness and independence of real coin tosses.) It's important for a coin to tumble many times before it falls.

Comment: I guess my question is poorly worded or I am uninformed but I dont see why the two scenarios I laid out are any different. Say you have some adversary who is pretending to flip a coin and after N flips you get to see the sequence. Assume that the sequence always has 50% heads and 50% tails is there a way to tell how likely it is that the coin flips were truly random?

Comment: My quibble with the statement about 500:500 is based on the fact that the most likely observations in the distribution BINOM(1000, .5) are around 500 Heads. Even though P(X=499), P(X = 500), P(X=501), and neighbors are among the most likely, they are still rare. I agree with you that I would be suspicious of a report of getting exactly 500 Heads out of 1000. // Even so, with 10 fair tosses HHHHHTTTT is as likely as HTTHHHTTT, but getting 5 Heads is still more likely than getting 2.

Comment: Im still unsure if I am getting my point across. Say we are playing a game where you score a point for every heads you flip plus some bonus points for how many heads were consecutive. Now my goal is to determine whether you actually flipped a coin or if you are trying to game the system and I can only observe the bit string representing the sequence of coin flips once you are done. Now obviously I cant just look at aggregate statistics because you can always report 50% heads and 50% tails but how can I detect your attempt to make heads consecutive?

Comment: I have carefully read what you said. You are confusing two issues. Both can be tested statistically, but not really at the same time. (1) Is the coin fair? If so, then the number of heads should be btw  469 and 531. (2) Are tosses independent, in that case you should see about 500 'runs'. A run is a sequence of repeated values. HHHTTTHTHT has 6 runs HHH, TTT, H, T, H, T.  A 'runs test' will check to see if your sequence of 1000 tosses has a reasonable number of runs, given its Heads probability // There are other tests for (1) and for (2), but know of no good way to test both at the same time.

Comment: It seems that a runs test is something very close to what I need. I understand that there is two issues here, I just already know how to check if a coin is fair and was asking about the second metric.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator has some discussion on tests on PRNGs to ensure they "look" random enough for practical purposes.  this is a pretty big and specialized topic and runs test is only scratching the surface.

Comment: @antkam Right. A runs test is only one method of checking independence (maybe the most common traditionally). Autocorrelation methods also widely used. // Vetting a PRNG is more intricate than checking whether coin tosses are independently made. // Magicians have also used [_rising sequences_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891564/how-many-types-of-mathematical-information-are-there/1891757#1891757) to exploit nonrandom order in a deck of cards.

Comment: Bayesian XOR Frequentist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some different *metrics* which can be used to indicate *randomness* when flipping a  coin. One of these is to analyze the length of longest runs.

> **Longest runs:**
>
> A run is a sequence of consecutive heads or tails. We can calculate the probability of runs of length $k$ of a fair coin via the generating function
>   \begin{align*}
> W_k(z)=\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-2z+z^{k+1}}
> \end{align*}
>   where the coefficient $[z^n]$ of $W_k(z)$ gives the number of possibilities to have runs of length $\leq k$ when flipping a coin $n$ times. The probability for a run having length $k$ is therefore
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{2^n}[z^n]\left(\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-2z+z^{k+1}}-\frac{1-z^{k}}{1-2z+z^{k}}\right)
> \end{align*}

The derivation of this generating function is given in detail in section I.4.1 in  *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick.

> They also cite a nice story attributed to T. Varga (p. 52) around this theme:
>
> - ''A class of high school children is divided into two sections. In one of the sections, each child is given a coin which he throws two hundred times, recording the resulting head and tail sequence on a piece of paper. In the other section, the children do not receive coins, but are told instead that they should try to write down a ‘random’ head and tail sequence of length two hundred. Collecting these slips of paper, [a statistician] then tries to subdivide them into their original groups. Most of the time, he succeeds quite well.”
>
>   The statistician’s secret is to determine the probability distribution of the maximum length of runs of consecutive letters in a random binary word of length $n$ (here $n=200$). The probability that this parameter equals $k$ is
>     \begin{align*}
>   \frac{1}{2^{200}}[z^{200}]\left(\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-2z+z^{k+1}}-\frac{1-z^{k}}{1-2z+z^{k}}\right)
>   \end{align*}
>     The probabilities are then easily computed using any symbolic package: for $n=200$, the values found are 
>     $$
>   \begin{array}{r|ccccc}
>   k&3&4&5&\color{blue}{6}&\color{blue}{7}\\
>   \hline\\
>   \mathbb{P}(k)&6.54\,10^{-8}&7.07\,10^{-4}&0.0339&\color{blue}{0.1660}&\color{blue}{0.2574}\\
>   \\
>   \\
>   k&\color{blue}{8}&\color{blue}{9}&\color{blue}{10}&\color{blue}{11}&\color{blue}{12}\\
>   \hline\\
>   \mathbb{P}(k)&\color{blue}{0.2235}&\color{blue}{0.1459}&\color{blue}{0.0829}&\color{blue}{0.00440}&\color{blue}{0.0226}\\
>   \end{array}
>   $$
>     Thus, in a randomly produced sequence of length $200$, there are usually runs of length $6$ or more: the probability of the event turns out to be close to $97\%$ (and there is still a probability of about $8\%$ to have a run of length $11$ or more). On the other hand most children (and adults) are usually afraid of writing down runs longer than $4$ or $5$ as this is felt as strongly “non-random”. The statistician simply selects the slips that contain runs of length $6$ or more as the true random ones. Voilà!

Another metric is the first and last equality of number of heads and tails when flipping a fair coin $n$ times. This is strongly connected with the so-called *Arcsine* law. The following is from chapter III: *Fluctuations in Coin Tossing and Random Walks* of the classic *[An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications, Vol. I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8126518057)* by W. Feller.

> **Arcsine law:**
>
> Let's assume we play a game, flipping a fair coin. We interprete resulting sequences of heads and tails as random walks starting in $(0,0)$ and going $(1,1)$ if head occurs and $(1,-1)$ if tail occurs.
>
> Then the following is valid: With probability $\frac{1}{2}$ no equalization occurs in the second half of the game regardless of the length of the game. Furthermore, the probabilities near the end point are *greatest*.
>
> This is due to the *Arcsine law for last visits* (see e.g. Vol 1, ch.3, section 4, Theorem 1 in W. Feller's book): The   probability that up  to  and  including epoch $2n$ the last  visit to the origin occurs at  epoch  $2k$ is   given by
>   \begin{align*}
> \alpha_{2k,2n}=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}
> \end{align*}
>   Since according to Stirling's  formula
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{2k}{k}\sim    \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi    k}}
> \end{align*}
>   it     can  be shown that for fixed $0<x<1$ and $n$ sufficiently large
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k<xn}\alpha_{2k,2n}\approx  \frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin \sqrt{x}
> \end{align*}

Other metrics are the number of changes of sign (more heads than tails or vice versa), first passages and returns to the origin,  the equidistribution of heads and tails, etc. Chapter III by W. Feller provides a thorough introduction.

Comment: Several nice answers in one (+1). The arcsin expression is the CDF of BETA(.5, .5).

Comment: @BruceET: Many thanks for the nice comment and the info.

Comment: I really like this answer both of these metrics seem likely to be useful. Thanks!

Comment: @Tpaul: You're welcome. :-)

Comment: +1. It looks like a strong academic lecture.

Comment: @FelixMarin: Many thanks for the credit, Felix. I've removed the broken link. The cited theorem is from Feller's book.

Answer (score 4):

Familiar testing and confidence interval methods have been used to check whether a process is ***fair***, producing equal numbers of Heads and Tails. Perhaps this discussion has reached the point were it is worthwhile to look separately at some methods to check whether a process produces Heads and Tails ***independently*** from trial to trial.

**Independent Process.** Roughly speaking, Markov chains may have one-step dependence, in which the next step depends (at most) on the current one. First, we look at a chain in which the steps are *purely independent.* You can think of it as successive tosses of an unfair
coin in which $P(Heads) = \theta = 1/3$ (designated `pp` for population proportion in the R code below).

We make the following four plots of this elementary process:

- Bar chart showing 0s (Tails) and 1s (Heads),
- Trace showing convergence of cumulative means of Head counts to 1/3
- History plot showing the value (H =1, T=0), for the first few steps.
- ACF (autocorrelation function) plot

.

```
set.seed(123)
m = 10000;  n = 1:m;  pp = 1/3;  x = rbinom(m, 1, pp)
s.x = cumsum(x);  t.x = s.x/n
par(mfrow=c(2,2)); RLE = rle(sort(x))
  barplot(RLE$lengths/m, names=c("0=Tail", "1=Heads"), main="Barchart")
  plot(t.x, type="l", lwd=2, ylim=c(0,1), main="Trace")
     abline(h=pp, col="green")
  plot(1:100, x[1:100], type="s", main="History")
  acf(x, ylim=c(-.1,.1), main="ACF Plot")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Roughly speaking, the ACF plot is found by looking at correlations of 'lags':

lag $0:$  $(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_m)$ vs $(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_m),$ for which the correlation is always $r = 1)$;
lag $1:$  $(X_2, X_3, \dots, X_m)$ vs $(X_1, X_2, \dots X_{m–1});$ 
lag $2:$  $(X_3, X_4, \dots, X_m)$ vs $(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{m–2});$ and so on.
(Actually, in finding all correlations, the sample mean and variance of all $m$ observations are used.)

In the four plots above: (i) The *Barchart* shows there are about $1/3$ Heads. 
(ii) The *Trace* shows that the cumulative proportion approaches $1/3$ according to the Law of Large Numbers.
(iii) The *History plot* shows cycles: a cycle from $0$ to $1$ and back to $0$ takes 
$1/\theta + 1/(1 – \theta) = 3 + 3/2 = 4.5$ steps on average.
(iv) The *ACF plot*  For this independent process shows that only about $5\%$ of lagged correlations $r$ lie outside the confidence band (blue dotted lines).

**Dependent Process.** Now we show a dependent process that roughly models
the rainy season of a so-called Mediterranean Climate. Rainly days (1) follow sunny days (0) with probability $\alpha =0.1,$ and sunny days follow rainy ones with probability $\beta = 0.2.$

```
set.seed(1237);  m = 10000;  w = numeric(m);  n = 1:m
alpha = 0.1;  beta = 0.2  # weather change probabilities
w[1] = 0                  # start with a sunny day
for (i in 2:m)  {
   if (w[i-1]==0)  w[i] = rbinom(1, 1, alpha)
   else            w[i] = rbinom(1, 1, 1 - beta)  }
s.w = cumsum(w);  t.w = s.w/n
par(mfrow=c(2,2));  RLE = rle(sort(w))
 barplot(RLE$lengths/m, names=c("0=Sun", "1=Rain"), main="Barchart")
 plot(t.w, type="l", lwd=2, ylim=c(0,1), xlab="Day", main="Trace")
  abline(h=alpha/(alpha+beta), col="green")
 plot(1:100, w[1:100], type="s", xlab="First 100 Days", main="History")
 acf(w, ylim=c(-.1,1), main="ACF Plot")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Here: (i) The *Barchart* shows  About $\alpha/(\alpha + \beta) = 1/3$ Rainy days. (ii) The *Trace* shows the cumulative proportion of Rainy day approaches $1/3.$ 
(iii) The *History* plot show longer cycles than in the independent
process.  One cycle: from Sunny to Rainy and back takes $1/\alpha + 1/\beta =$ $10 + 5 = 15$ days on average.
(iv) The *ACF* plot shows that dependence on the current day's weather "wears off" after about 10-12 days. But autocorrelation for the first few lags is
significantly positive.

Comment: Very nice and instructive answer. (+1)

Comment: great answer! I will bookmark this!